# Handlebars block helpers screwed up in HAML

Tags: haml, handlebars.js

I need to use some handlebars block helpers inside of an element's attribute. How can I get

```
.some.class{:class => "{{if property}} otherClass {{/if}}"}
```

to parse properly? Here is the compiled output as is:

```
<div class='class otherClass property}} some {{/if}} {{if'></div>
```

I've tried escaping every non-word character, trying single quotes, and adjusting the spacing, but nothing seems to fix it. I'm hoping to find a more elegant solution than just using the :plain keyword.

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question (or apparently I can't for another 6 hours), but I actually found a solution that works here. There seems to be an issue with the way haml is combining classes from the attributes with the ones from the "dot chain". Changing it to this seems to work fine.

%div{:class => "some class {{if property}} otherClass {{/if}}"}

Comment: If you post your solution as an answer, I will vote it up as an answer for ya. That trick totally worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that you need to add some character before the {{}} for Haml to accept it. For example:

```
%div.some.class{:class => "a{{foo}}"}
```

Not idea, but suites my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the trick doesn't work for anything handlebars expression that is moderately complex.

In the end I resolved this by using string literals in haml. So in the example case shown in the question. The below haml is needed, remember to close your tag, which is the last line.

```
\ <div class='class {{if property}} otherClass {{/if}} some '>
-# Normal haml goes here and must not start at the same indent as the above literal
\ </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all the classes in to the class attribute instead of using both the class shorthand dot notation and a class attribute.

```
.col-md-12.card{ class: "{{toLowerCase level_name}}-master-card" }
```

becomes

```
%div{ class: "col-md-12 card {{toLowerCase level_name}}-master-card" }
```

HAML 4.0.7